# Google Sheets - query contains array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a range with a name column.

I also have a list of names chosen be presented.

I want to run a query which will select data from this range only if it names is inside this list:

```
Select C Where A "is in the selected array of names"
```

What would be the right way of doing that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose the array of names is D2:D10; then you could use the query string

```
"select C where A = '" & join("' or A = '", D2:D10) & "'"
```

This creates a long query string A = 'name' or A= 'another name'...

If the range of names is variable (e.g., you want all names listed in D2:D), replace D2:D10 with `filter(D2:D, len(D2:D))`.

Answer (score 2):

`QUERY` [doesn't have a concept of in](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

If you have your list of names in column A, say

```
  A  B  C
1 1     A
2 2     B
3 3     C
```

And you name of names to find in D1:D2

```
  D
1 A
2 C
```

You can build a regex to match the names you want to find in E1

```
=QUERY(C1:C3, "SELECT A WHERE A MATCHES '(" & JOIN("|", D1:D2) & ")'")
```

which returns

```
  E
1 A
2 C
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide the list of names in the query rather than another range you can use **matches**

Exact match:

```
=QUERY(A1:C3; "SELECT C WHERE A matches 'name1|name2|name3' ")
```

Match part of a name:

```
=QUERY(A1:C3; "SELECT C WHERE A matches '.*name1.*|.*name2.*' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or blend both methods, and set it so you can use additional filters...

```
=query(A1:A, "SELECT A,B,C WHERE (A MATCHES '("& JOIN("|", filter(D1:D, LEN(D1:D))) &")' OR C = 'Criteria' ")
```